# Is Outlook UserProperty being transferred when the AppointmentItem is sent to another user?

Tags: outlook-addin

I use a UserProperty to store custom specific information in an Outlook AppointmentItem. Now my question is whether this information is being transferred to the recipients of the AppointmentItem when the invitation is being sent?

If this is NOT sent with the AppointmentItem, how can I transfer custom info with the invitation and how can I code this in the AppointmentItem (or the object needed for that?)

Best regards
Hannes

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not. Keep in mind that `AppointmentItem` is never sent. When you call `AppointmentItem.Send`, it creates a new `MeetingItem` object and sends it instead.

You can trap the `Application.ItemSend` event, check that you are processing a `MeetingItem` object, retrieve the corresponding `AppointmentItem` object using `MeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment`, then copy the user properties from `AppointmentItem`  to `MeetingItem`. Keep in mind that user properties (which are stored as named MAPI properties) will only persist if the `MeetingItem` is sent in the TNEF format, e.g. between two Exchange mailboxes in the same domain. If it is converted to the iCal format, named properties will be gone.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation: Can I add X-fields to the invitation MeetingItem? Or am I allowed to change the GlobalAppointmentID?

Comment: You can try to add an X-Header MIME fields - see. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c359189a-aa03-4a21-9666-35007f4d0173/outlook-2016-64bitcan-we-tag-xheader-on-taskmeetingcalendar-item?forum=outlookdev

Comment: Not sure about GlobalAppointmentID - OOM won't let you change it, but Extended MAPI or Redemption can. Not sure why you'd want to - and the id needs to be in a very specific format.

Comment: my external app transfers a globalappointmentId with ics and thus it is possible for the outlook id to retrieve this special id. But when the outlook addin creates an appointment Outlook/MAPI/Exchange creates the appointmentId.

Comment: But that means you have to reset it on the appointment, not the meeting item. I don't think OOM would let you do that, you'd need Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption for that.